# How to port Qt webkit on the iMX board

Tags: cross-compiling, qtwebkit

I have cross compiled the QT web kit for iMX6 board. now i have to dump it on board and test it.
So how to dump it on to the board and how to test it or open the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a rootfs using rootstock, then apt-get install these libs/test apps